# How do I handle when user taps on local notification in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am so frustrated with the Xamarin documentations. I am looking at doing one of the most basic thing, which is:

**When a local notification comes out, a user taps the notification. It launches the App.**
**How do I handle this so that the app launches and acts according to the notification?**

This is the official Xamarin Local Notifications documentation....
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications

In Stack Overflow or google searches I can't find any Solutions.

Nothing is mentioned on how to act on a tap to the notification

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes, the docs can be improved! They just assume that you understand it, you should add a pull request or an issue to improve that page!

After you have created:

- The INotificationManager interface in the Core project,
- The iOS platform changes- iOSNotificationManager, iOSNotificationReceiver, AppDelegate changes
- The Android platform changes- AndroidNotificationManager, MainActivity changes, if needed BroadcastReceiver

Then in the constructor of the page where you want to handle the changes, get the instance of the NotificationManager, and then subscribe to the NotificationReceived event which should get called when a user taps on the notification item.

```
public DashboardPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    notificationManager = DependencyService.Get<INotificationManager>();
    notificationManager.NotificationReceived += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        var evtData = (NotificationEventArgs)eventArgs;
        Console.WriteLine("Title & Message: " + evtData.Title + evtData.Message);
    };
}
```

Comment: Salam Saamer, always a pleasure to receive your answers. But isn't this for when the notification arrives from the Alarm Manager? I'm looking for when the notification is actually tapped by the user. It will launch the application. I want the application to serve in the context of the notification

Comment: Walaikumsalam! @user1034912! This should be the same way to get notifications on iOS, can you check in the sample project to see if it works on Android as well?

Comment: Apparentlyt now even scheduled notifications from the AlarmManager is not working for me... very frustrating!

Comment: Try to place a breakpoint and Console Log in the iOS Notification Manager and Receiver and see if those get hit

Answer (score 1):

You could try Plugin.LocalNotification too, it has a feature can hanle tap event, like:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Local Notification tap event listener
        NotificationCenter.Current.NotificationTapped += OnLocalNotificationTapped;

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
    
    private void OnLocalNotificationTapped(NotificationEventArgs e)
        {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

edit:

On iOS:
You can add code in DidRecieveNotiticationResponse(),like:

```
   public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
        {
            if (response.IsDefaultAction)
            {
                ProcessNotification(response.Notification);
            }
           Console.WriteLine("Called");
          App.Current.MainPage=new Page();
            completionHandler();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to avoid adding another library....my app is already taking almost 2 seconds to startup